# How can I get the path to the current target directory in my build.sbt

Tags: scala, sbt

In my `build.sbt` I want to know the current target file. Something like this:

```scala
val targetFile = ??? // /home/fbaierl/Repos/kcc/scala/com.github.fbaierl/target/scala-2.12/myapplication_2.12-1.2.3-SNAPSHOT.jar
```

With `target.value` I only get the directory up until /target. Is there any way to get the full path to the resulting jar?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you need is the return value of `compile:package`.

Run `sbt "show compile:package"` to see that it prints full path to the artifact you are building.

If you just need the path without building the artifact, do `sbt "show Compile / packageBin / artifactPath"`

In order to use this value in `build.sbt`, you have to define a `task` or `setting` like this

```
val targetFile = taskKey[File]("shows target file")

targetFile := {
  val path = artifactPath.in(packageBin).in(Compile).value
  //same as val path = (Compile / packageBin / artifactPath).value
  streams.value.log.info(path.toPath.toString)
  path
}
```

A value of any task in sbt cannot be directly assigned to a val like `val someFile: File`. You have to write your custom logic in terms of settings and tasks.

Comment: How would I call that in my `build.sbt`?

Comment: Is it really necessary to call local variables in SBT "value"?

Comment: :) no. Used IDEA for a value extraction. Btw, just failed an interview and one the points was "bad variable naming"

Comment: Uhm... Yeah... My condolences. I think this answer could be improved significantly by removing all the strange stuff with `taskKey`s, and simply replacing it by `val targetFile: File  = (Compile / packageBin / artifactPath).value`.

Comment: No, that's not possible in sbt. value extraction is only possible in task/settings definition body `:= {???}`.

Comment: @IvanStanislavciuc Well, yes, since all SBT does is defining a dag of tasks, that's kind of obvious, why build an unnecessary do-nothing wrapper task around it?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/189688/discussion-between-ivan-stanislavciuc-and-andrey-tyukin).

Answer (score 1):

In most recent 1.x style, it should be something like

```
  val targetFile: File = (Compile / packageBin / artifactPath).value
```

Comment: This does not compile `build.sbt:52: error: `value` can only be used within a task or setting macro, such as :=, +=, ++=, Def.task, or Def.setting.
val targetFile: File = (Compile / packageBin / artifactPath).value`

Comment: @IvanStanislavciuc Exactly. Just like you cannot use `val`s and `def`s outside of class / object / package-object definitions in ordinary scala code. I assume that this is clear, and don't see any reason to point it out every time. Global structure of SBT's build files is not the topic of the question.